# FFmpeg 0.11.1 rtmp mp4 streaming issues

Tags: linux, pandaboard

I am using ffmpeg 0.11.1 onto a panda board for streaming. Linux linaro-developer 3.4.0-1-linaro-lt-omap #1~120625232503-Ubuntu Sx Ubuntu os.

I want to live stream a raw video from a video device or a cam to a rtmp server in an mp4 format, command used:

```
./ffmpeg \
-f alsa -async 1   -ac 2 -i hw:2,0  \
-f video4linux2  -i /dev/video0  \
-acodec aac -b:a 40k \
-r 50 -s 320x240 -vcodec libx264 -strict -2  -b:v 320K -pass 1 \
-f flv  rtmp://...../mp4:demo101
```

By this command I am able to stream but fps varies between 8 to 7 6 and so on.  Help me to figure it out.

Comment: Your cpu load will be very high. Reduce your libx264 preset.